# ORA-00913: too many values with a nested case

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I am currently working on my first year assignment to build a database using Oracle Apex and am trying to create a report with fields to filter the table displayed. To do this using 2 parameters (in this case date of a dentist appointment and the staff member performing said appointment)I am using a nested case to check each field. I am getting the Error:

ORA-06550: line 6, column 23: ORA-00913: too many values.

Me, my fellow students and my tutors are failing to see how to fix it. Hoping someone here can see my mistake.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT 
CASE :P5_APPOINTMENT_DATE
    WHEN (NULL)
        THEN CASE :P5_STAFF
            WHEN (NULL)
                THEN (select
                      APPOINTMENT_ID AS "Appointment ID",
                      Patient.Surname AS "Patient Surname",
                      Patient.Forename AS "Patient Forename",
                      Staff.Surname AS "Staff Surname",
                      A_DATE AS "Date"
                      FROM Appointment
                      Inner Join Patient ON Patient.Patient_ID = Appointment.Patient_ID
                      Inner Join Staff ON Staff.Staff_ID = Appointment.Staff_ID)

                ELSE (select
                      APPOINTMENT_ID AS "Appointment ID",
                      Patient.Surname AS "Patient Surname",
                      Patient.Forename AS "Patient Forename",
                      Staff.Surname AS "Staff Surname",
                      A_DATE AS "Date"
                      FROM Appointment
                      Inner Join Patient ON Patient.Patient_ID = Appointment.Patient_ID
                      Inner Join Staff ON Staff.Staff_ID = Appointment.Staff_ID
                      Where STAFF.STAFF_ID = :P5_STAFF) 
                END 


        ELSE CASE :P5_STAFF
            WHEN (NULL)
                THEN (select
                      APPOINTMENT_ID AS "Appointment ID",
                      Patient.Surname AS "Patient Surname",
                      Patient.Forename AS "Patient Forename",
                      Staff.Surname AS "Staff Surname",
                      A_DATE AS "Date"
                      FROM Appointment
                      Inner Join Patient ON Patient.Patient_ID = Appointment.Patient_ID
                      Inner Join Staff ON Staff.Staff_ID = Appointment.Staff_ID
                      Where A_DATE = :P5_APPOINTMENT_DATE)
                ELSE (select
                      APPOINTMENT_ID AS "Appointment ID",
                      Patient.Surname AS "Patient Surname",
                      Patient.Forename AS "Patient Forename",
                      Staff.Surname AS "Staff Surname",
                      A_DATE AS "Date"
                      FROM Appointment
                      Inner Join Patient ON Patient.Patient_ID = Appointment.Patient_ID
                      Inner Join Staff ON Staff.Staff_ID = Appointment.Staff_ID
                      Where A_DATE = :P5_APPOINTMENT_DATE AND STAFF.Surname = :P5_STAFF)
                END

        END
        FROM APPOINTMENT
```

Comment: A `case` returns only a single value.  Your subqueries are returning multiple values.  Rephrase your query to be something else.  Or, delete this question and ask another one, providing sample data and desired results and a description of what you are trying to do.

Comment: If you are trying to run different queries based on parameter I would use `IF/ELSE` logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Gordon Linoff said in a comment, a `case` returns a single value. Since the bulk of the subqueries are the same and you're only varying the filter conditions, you can move the `case` to the `where` clause; except here you don't even really need a case, you can get the same effect with `or`, something like:

```
SELECT APPOINTMENT_ID AS "Appointment ID",
  Patient.Surname AS "Patient Surname",
  Patient.Forename AS "Patient Forename",
  Staff.Surname AS "Staff Surname",
  A_Date AS "Date"
FROM Appointment
JOIN Patient ON Patient.Patient_ID = Appointment.Patient_ID
JOIN Staff ON Staff.Staff_ID = Appointment.Staff_ID
WHERE (:P5_APPOINTMENT_DATE IS NULL OR A_Date = :P5_APPOINTMENT_DATE)
AND (:P5_STAFF IS NULL OR STAFF.Surname = :P5_STAFF);
```

If both bind variables are null you'll get all records; if either or both are not null then you'll get the subset of matching values. Which seems to be what you want - four possible outcomes depending on which of the two variables are set.

Comment: So simple but I just couldn't see it, I knew there was something wrong with using case but my tutors were no help with an alternative thanks a lot for your help.